# Retrieve specific element from dynamic array in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Right, I'm new to swift(ui) and have been experimenting - my current issue is to do with a basic card app.
I have generated a deck of card objects (in this case 10 items) and first displayed them all in a stack using a ForEach loop - no problem there.
I then went on to pull out one card from the array to display on it's own nd this is where everything comes to a crashing halt. I suspect it's something simple and obvious but how do I get a single card from my deck for display?

```
struct Card: Identifiable, Equatable{
let id = UUID()
var factor1: Int = 0
var factor2: Int = 0
var product: Int = 0
var possibleAnswers: [Int] = []
}
struct CardView: View{
let card: Card
var body: some View{
    VStack {
    VStack { // Actual Card
        Spacer()
            Text("\(card.factor1) X \(card.factor2)")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
               // .bold()
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    .background(
      Rectangle()
           .foregroundColor(cardColor(of: card))
    )
    
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ForEach(card.possibleAnswers, id:\.self) { answer in
                Text("\(answer)")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 50)
                    .background(
                      Rectangle()
                           .foregroundColor(cardColor(of: card))
                    )
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding()

    }
}

func cardColor(of card: Card) -> Color {
    return Color(red:228/255, green: 229/255, blue: 229/255)
}
}

class Deck: ObservableObject {
@Published var numberCards = 10
@Published var cards = [Card]()

func buildDeck() {
    cards.removeAll()
    let cardCount = 1...self.numberCards
    for _ in cardCount {
                // Set up new card
                var myCard = Card()
                myCard.factor1 = .random(in: 1...12)
                myCard.factor2 = .random(in: 1...12)
                myCard.product = myCard.factor1 * myCard.factor2
                myCard.possibleAnswers.append(myCard.product)
                for _ in 0...2{
                    myCard.possibleAnswers.append(Int.random(in: 1..<145))
                }
                myCard.possibleAnswers.shuffle()
                // add card to the deck
                self.cards.append(myCard)
    }
}

var count: Int {
    return cards.count
}
}


struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var deck = Deck()
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
                deck.buildDeck()
        }) { // button text
            Text("Click to add card. Current Number of cards in deck: \(deck.count)")
        }
        Spacer()
    ZStack {
//             ForEach(deck.cards) { card in
        if let card = deck.cards[0] {
           CardView(card: card)
        }
//           }
    }
        Spacer()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `withAnimation {`. But what's the error?

Comment: Getting an index out of range for some reason

Comment: Hmm... try commenting out as many lines of code as you can, until Xcode stops crashing. Then gradually add them back in.

Comment: I'm off to work but I'll give that a go when I get back

Comment: If possible try to provide a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is it crashing when it runs this function? Is cards.removeAll removing all cards in your deck? Does the view crash when it reaches this line? I think in your view, it may just be worth protecting your let card = deck.cards[0] by using if let instead

Comment: The RemoveAll is there to ensure a 'clean' deck and clears the array before adding a new set of cards. Using Let works if the statement is deck.cards.first but still crashes if given an index, deck.cards[0]

Comment: Yeah, crashing is the expected behaviour, because you are trying to access an element at `index` 0 while the array is `empty`

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided, it looks like this error was caused by accessing an index that an array doesn't even have in the first place.

In this case, you're accessing the first element of `cards` while in `buildDeck` function you removed all the elements which may be the cause of the error while  it's:

```
let card = deck.cards[0]
CardView(card: card)
```

You can try to use `if let` to make sure the element is present before accessing it.

```
if let card = deck.cards.first {
   CardView(card: card)
}
```

Comment: works as far as displaying the first card in the deck but with a specific index the code still crashes

Comment: This is because the element at the specific index (0 in this case) you're passing is not found, so Swift throws an exception saying that the index is out of range

Comment: When using `if let card = deck.cards.first {` we make sure that the element exists before we can use if